# Prerequisites for AIC/BIC model comparison

Tags: aic, bic, multilevel-analysis

I have a question about model selection when using AIC/BIC. So, if two model structures are totally different, can I still directly apply AIC and BIC?
Also, for a hierarchical model, how to compute the total number of parameters when computing AIC and BIC?
Thanks.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by model structures?

Comment: For Example, one is Multinomial Logistic Regression, another one is Hierarchical Gamma.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of AIC and BIC is that they let you compare the fits of non-nested models. So as long both models are fit to the *same* data set, a comparison seems justified even if they are "totally different".
As for the number of free parameters in a hierarchical model, I think you should use the number of parameters that are being estimated, which means (1) the fixed effects, (2) the random effects *variance components*, and (3) the covariances of the random effects, if any. This thread provides a more in-depth discussion: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2012q3/019121.html

Comment: Just to add some extra bits - you need to ensure normalising constants are included in the maximised log - likelihood. Also the likelihood used in multi level modeling should be the integrated/marginal likelihood (ie random effects integrated out).